# How to set PhoneNumber in AspNetUsers table when using individual user accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have created a new Asp.Net Web API project and used the authentication type "Individual User Accounts" which created a database with some default tables. 
I then created a number of accounts with emails and passwords successfully.
When the user is registering, I want them to input an email address, a password and a phone number which should add the corresponding values to the corresponding columns in the AspNetUsers table.

I have successfully managed to add the email address and password but how can I add the phone number?

So far, I in the account controller I have edited the register method to submit the PhoneNumber

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

I have also edited the RegisterBindingModedl to incorporate the PhoneNumber property

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(11, ErrorMessage = "The telephone number must be 11 characters long.", MinimumLength = 11)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

When I submit the phone number following using postman

```
{
    "Email": "test@gmail.com",
    "Password": ".Password123.",
    "ConfirmPassword": ".Password123.",
    "PhoneNumber": "01642333333"
}
```

The user is submitted to the database it gives a 200 response and submits.
When I view the database in the database, the user appears but the PhoneNumber is null.

How can I add a user with a PhoneNumber?

Comment: You're forgetting to add the phone number to the model change `var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, EmailConfirmed = true };`this line into this line `var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber, EmailConfirmed = true };
`

Comment: I've my code to change that, and it still doesn't work. I've edited the code above how I edited it in my code

Answer (score 1):

In your Register post method after you create the user try calling

```cs
await _usermanager.SetPhoneNumberAsync(user, model.PhoneNumber)
```

Comment: I've edited my code and edited the code in the question I posted to what you have suggested but the result is still the same. The PhoneNumber isn't saved to the database as expected.

Comment: Put a breakpoint inside your code and see if it actually holds value @CraigMartin

Comment: @CraigMartin Updated my answer